# marginBottom is not working to my ImageView in android

Tags: android, android-layout

When I am applying padding 5dp to an ImageView (size 50x50), then the result is coming height and width is 50x50 include padding.

How can I resolve this problem in Android?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#cccccc" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user11" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And what did you expect? and margin or padding? its two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is inside the view bounds, margin is outside. So adding padding of 5dp will cause the view content area to be `width - (padding * 2)`. Margin won't affect the view bounds but causes neighboring views to be at least as far away from the view as the set margin.

Answer (score 0):

change your relative layout's height from:
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
to
**android:layout_height="match_parent"**
or something more than your imageview's height say, 60dp etc.